# Error in cmd whlie installing CPPYY on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, cppyy

I have been trying to install [Cppyy](https://pypi.org/project/cppyy/) on my computerbut I'm new to this so I don't know a whole lot about this I have python and pip install on my computer

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python --version
Python 3.8.6

C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip --version
pip 20.2.3
```

when I try to run

> pip install cppyy

cmd gives me error

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z4gw8trb\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'CPyCppyy==1.11.4; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' 'cppyy-backend==1.14.0; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' 'cppyy-cling==6.21.3; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' 'cppyy-cling<=6.18.2.3; python_implementation == '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' setuptools wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (42 lines):
  Ignoring cppyy-cling: markers 'platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"' don't match your environment
  Collecting CPyCppyy==1.11.4
    Using cached CPyCppyy-1.11.4.tar.gz (178 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hj42_3n3\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cppyy-cling>=6.21.3' 'cppyy-backend>=1.14' setuptools wheel
         cwd: None
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Collecting cppyy-cling>=6.21.3
      Using cached cppyy_cling-6.21.3-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (18.2 MB)
    Collecting cppyy-backend>=1.14
      Using cached cppyy-backend-1.14.0.tar.gz (32 kB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Getting requirements to build wheel: started
      Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing wheel metadata: started
        Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
    Collecting setuptools
      Using cached setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
    Collecting wheel
      Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: cppyy-backend
      Building wheel for cppyy-backend (PEP 517): started
      Building wheel for cppyy-backend (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpojxb8d41'
           cwd: C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-znkz3pmg\cppyy-backend
      Complete output (6 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      checking for build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cppyy-backend
    Failed to build cppyy-backend
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for cppyy-backend which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
    ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hj42_3n3\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cppyy-cling>=6.21.3' 'cppyy-backend>=1.14' setuptools wheel Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\sarfaraz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z4gw8trb\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'CPyCppyy==1.11.4; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' 'cppyy-backend==1.14.0; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' 'cppyy-cling==6.21.3; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' 'cppyy-cling<=6.18.2.3; python_implementation == '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' setuptools wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

I found some instruction on the site but it was hard for me to follow it since I'm new to this stuff

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the setuptools wheel installed ?

Comment: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/` should be your guide. Without the MSVC compiler installed, `cppyy` is useless anyway.

Comment: yes setuptools wheel is istalled

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade setuptools wheel

```
pip install -U setuptools wheel
```

End then try

```
pip install cppyy --no-index
```

If not help, that problem may by with **python 3.8**
By PyPi it’s **supported <=3.7**

Comment: for pip install -U setuptools wheel  Requirement already up-to-date:                                                   for pip install cppyy --no-index   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cppyy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cppyy

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the error message and mentioned already by hoefling, you need a system compiler, at the very minimum for system headers, but also for C++ library headers. Cling needs the code from these headers to parse any new C++ code you may give it that uses C++ standard library or Windows system features.

In principle, it's possible to ship a precompiled header with cppyy-cling that contains all system and C++ headers as IR bitcode, but MSVC likes to change header include guards between versions, so that would then *only* work if there is *no* system compiler. (It's somewhat better on Linux, but it, too, has changed include guard names in some instances.) This will be revisited once Cling supports precompiled modules (PCMs; as opposed to headers) on Windows. Then these PCMs can be prepackaged and installed conditionally if no system compiler is available. Module support in upstream is, however, still very fresh and not even released yet, so this is something that will only appear in the medium-term.

Anyway, MSVC is free these days. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I was wondering which version of MSVC do u suppose I install on my windows because after downloading from here 'https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/' there were alot of option and alot of version to those option. I did install the one that was latest version of MSVC but it still gives me error. I'm new to this so don't know much about it.

Comment: Latest version is fine, as long as it includes the C++ tools. Next, you need to make sure that the tools are available in your environment, either by running the setup script directly, or by starting a command prompt that has this done. See the "walkthrough" link on the page that you reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019